# WSO2 EI 6.0 running in docker

Tags: wso2

Has WSO2 released any information or resources for running EI 6.0 in docker?

I see nothing on their homepage yet.

BTW. What happened to BRS? See no use of the newly packaged suite without it.

Thanks.